# How to test python code on multiple platforms?

Tags: python

I found a few online python interpreters, and I could test some code on some of them, but they are all running on Linux. Is there an online python interpreter that runs on windows or mac? Or is there some other way one could easily* test some python code on other platforms?

*Without having to buy and setup each OS I want to test.

Comment: You'll have to buy them, or rent them. I think that's your choice..

Comment: If you use an EC2 instance you can test your code on Windows and Linux, however for Mac you will have to rent it from another company.

Answer (score 3):

Every tester that I'm aware of tests against actual installations or on virtual machines.

[Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is one virtual machine that I've had a lot of success with on Ubuntu Linux for other distributions of Linux and my machine licensed Windows copy.

The `os` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) describes the cross-compatibility of many of its functions, if you're using that a lot.

Comment: Regarding Windows: [modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) provides already configured virtual machines.

Comment: Or then [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) combined with [vagrant-windows](https://github.com/WinRb/vagrant-windows) may lessen pain of setting up windows VM.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to set up and use [IPython Notebook on Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-python-ipython-notebook/).

From linked article:

> .. This VM is a complete operating system in the cloud and will be used to run the IPython Notebook ..

You can then access that VM using remote desktop:
["How to log on to the virtual machine after you create it"](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-tutorial/#logon)

---

If you are into writing unit tests, then [travis-ci](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci) may be of interest. And it claims support Python on OS/X: ["The OS X Build Environment"](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/)

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but IPython tends to mess with the internals, and I wouldn't trust it to demonstrate cross-platform compatibility, but +1 for the creative idea. AWS or a similar service could be employed this way.